# Google App Engine php, app.yaml - matching files without extension

Tags: php, regex, google-app-engine

ultimately im trying to route any request that does not have a file extension to be served as an html file
but i cannot get the regexp used in the url handler to work

i have reduced the app.yaml file to

```
handlers:
# extensionless file format
- url: /^([^.]+)$
  script: hndl.php

#root
- url: /
  script: root.php

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: script.php

- url: /.+
  script: index.php
```

but any url without an extension is handled by index.php

can anybody help me with the correct regexp to match urls without a filename extension and also explain why the above regexp is not working, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex is incorrect, you're trying to use the '^' that marks the begging of the string or line after you've already specified a '/' as the start of the string.

Try

```
handlers:
- url: /([^.]+)
  script: hndl.php
```

If you just want to serve the html files statically, rather then calling a php script then try

```
handler:
- url: /([^.]+)
  static_files: \1.html
  upload: .*\.html
```